# Scale LinearLayouts childs so they fit on Screen

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Hi I'm trying to make a Game-Menu with an AdMob banner at the Bottom. I want to draw the Menu on a SurfaceView. To seperate the Banner and the SurfaceView I used a LinearLayout. The Problem is that the SurfaceView is fullscreen and pushes the Banner outside the Screen (at the bottom). Is there anyway to scale the SurfaceView so it does not push the Banner outside the Screen ? (SurfaceView Height - Banner Height).
Here is my Code :

```
    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setId(Constants.LINLAY_ID);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    contentView = new ContentView(this);

    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    linearLayout.addView(contentView);
    linearLayout.addView(adView);
    setContentView(linearLayout);
```

`
Note : If I change it to :

```
linearLayout.addView(adView);
linearLayout.addView(contentView);
```

The banner shows on top and the SurfaceView gets pushed a little bit down.
Thank you for answers :)

Comment: if you want your surfaceciew to have full screen then with linear layout you can't show other view on the top of view

Comment: use frame layout and add your banner to bottom and add surface view to match parent

Comment: But wont the Banner Overlay the SurfaceView at the Bottom then ?

Comment: ok then use only linear layout with layout weight as a ratio as you want with height as 0dp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use layout weight in linear layout as :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <SurfaceView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

replace Textview with your bannerview

Use following to set layout weight dynamically

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    0f,
    1.0f
);
YOUR_VIEW.setLayoutParams(param);
```

here third parameter is for layout weight

Comment: Sorry for beeing so incompetent with this xD but do u know how I can set all this in Java code. Because I created the SurfaceView as a Class extending SurfaceView in the Code

Comment: Note : I tryed it in xml and it worked but I couldnt use both Views how i needet them

Comment: Thank you ! Works perfect :)